# Getting Oracle errors while importing with impdp

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I'm trying to do an import using `impdp` utility. but I'm Seeting

```
impdp system/system remap_schema=ieulive:ieusystem directory=pump_dir dumpfile=IEULIVE.DMP logfile=imp.log

ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

thats's what I get when I use `nologfile=y` option

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "F:\data_pump\IEULIVE.DMP"
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: <os 5> access is denied
```

I read that its a permission issue. I have imported before onto this DB, now I'm not able to do so.
I tried everything on the internet but didn't get the solution.
Thank you for your help

Updated
when I installed oracle, I used the windows virtual account(which I don't know what it is exactly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the permissions for the folder or for the specific file are not set correctly. Both must be accessible (read/write for the directory, at least read for the file) by the account which is running the Oracle processes, which is most likely the Windows SYSTEM account. Is F: a local disk drive or a network-mounted drive? On Windows network-mounted drives generally cannot be accessed using directory objects...

Comment: I was about to edit my post about the windows account. when I installed the oracle, I used the windows virtual account. F: is a local drive

Comment: Then it is most likely a permissions issue on the actual dump file. Not sure why it would be different now, since this has worked for you before. Are you running any kind of anti-virus software? If so, have you excluded these directories from scanning, and especially from on-access scanning?

Answer (score 1):

> directory=pump_dir

Your default data pump directory location and the actual directory where you have placed your export dump files could be different.

> ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "F:\data_pump\IEULIVE.DMP"

Verify the data pump directory matches with `"F:\data_pump\IEULIVE.DMP"`:

```
SELECT DIRECTORY_PATH FROM dba_directories WHERE DIRECTORY_NAME = 'PUMP_DIR';
```

If it matches, then you need to set the appropriate permissions to the directory and files.

Comment: I have created it myself before, and also imported in, but now I'm getting thess errors